# (Unity3D) Standard asset joystick does not work properly

Tags: ios, mobile, input, unity-game-engine

I am using the joystick script from the standard assets [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351) for a mobile game. On one side of the screen I have the joystick for movement, and on the other side I have two buttons for jump and attack. The problem I have is when I am using the joystick to move and then hit jump or attack, the joystick goes to the other side of the screen where I hit the button  (the joystick acts like I slid my finger to the other side of the screen)

How can I alter the script so that the joystick doesn't respond to any other touch events when I already have 1 finger on the joystick?